# how to share vars between methods?

Tags: c#

Ive coded for a bit on unity, however I began to start working with just c#.
However, ive noticed that unlike unity, I can not put

```
Class Program{
public string blah = 5;
}
```

and then use it in a method.
I made this little test for it:

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        public string test;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            test = "hi!!";
            Console.WriteLine(test);
            Main2();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        public static void Main2(){
            Console.WriteLine(test);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

and then it comes back saying an object reference is required for the non-static field...

I know that I can just make the var inside a method, however I don't seem to be able to call it from other methods.
So how do I make it so I can call a variable from all methods inside a class?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Instead of defining test as public string test, change it to public static string test. Hope this helps

Comment: Make it `public static string test;` instead

Comment: Static methods can only access static class members.

Comment: Also, don't try to assign an integer to a string (your first example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your methods are `static`. You need to use instance methods (remove static), or pass instance of `class` that contains your `public` property as an argument to your function.

For example:

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public string test;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var program = new Program();
            program.test = "hi!!";
            Console.WriteLine(program.test);
            Main2(program);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        public static void Main2(Program program){
            Console.WriteLine(program.test);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static string test;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            test = "hi!!";
            Console.WriteLine(test);
            Main2();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        public static void Main2(){
            Console.WriteLine(test);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable you've declared is an instance field, which means only instances of the class can set it (and it can be different for each instance). But the methods you're using are `static`, and they do not have access to any instance fields (or methods).

Typically the way to solve this is to make the variable `static` if you want to use it in `static` methods:

```
class Program
{
    public static string test;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test = "hi!!";
        Console.WriteLine($"Inside 'Main' method, 'test' == '{test}'");

        Main2();

        Console.Write("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void Main2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Inside 'Main2' method, 'test' == '{test}'");
    }
}
```